# Copy files from server1 to server2 using Jenkins job without using scp in shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Good day,
I am trying to solve the task without using scp in the shell script, is there any plugin that could make it like an embedded feature?

The task is to copy the dump file of the SQL database from the DB server to the backup server using the Jenkins job.

I solve it using "scp" in the script but is there another way?

Thank you

Comment: So you want the plugin, that will do the same as what scp does, but from groovy? But why?

Comment: Try the Publish Over SSH plugin - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/.

Comment: @markalex, Hello, I thought there might be some other program or plugin. Thank you

Comment: @DibakarAditya, Hello, 
Yes, I was thinking of it, but I couldn't find any clear example of how to do this.
Can you please provide some good examples for my case?

Comment: [Stash/Unstash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build). Mind you, `tar` (or `dd` or `nc`)  piped to an `ssh` and `untar` is a highly effective means of [transferring large files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/how-can-i-best-copy-large-numbers-of-small-files-over-scp).